# How to get the dates in an array in iOS swift?

Tags: swift

I have an array like:

```
["2018-03-21 11:09:25","2018-03-22 11:09:25","2018-03-23 11:09:25","2018-03-24 11:09:25"]
```

I need to display only dates [2018-03-21] in this array. How to split this array?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have and want Strings, here is a way you could use with Swift 4:

```
var myArray = [String]()
for date in dateArray {

    myArray.append(date.split(" ")[0])

}
```

Comment: Or simply `let resultArray = dateArray.map { $0.split(" ")[0] }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your task in subtasks to make it easy for you.

## How to transform your data?

Given an your input `2018-03-21 11:09:25` and your ouput `2018-03-21`, there are several ways.

I see 3 regular ways here (there are more of course):

1. Splitting with the space character as a delimiter and take the first part
2. Using a `DateFormatter`
3. Using `substring` to the `10th` character

As 2. seems overkill and 3. would need to work with ranges (I'm lazy), let's take 1. as an example:

`let ouput = input.split(" ")[0]`

## How to apply to the whole array?

You have many options, again, but the simpler is `map`.

Given your initial array is called `array`.

## Solution

`let result = array.map { $0.split(" ")[0] }`